# How can I check postgres database in docker volume?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I followed the tutorial from [prisma.io](https://www.prisma.io/docs/1.34/get-started/01-setting-up-prisma-new-database-JAVASCRIPT-a002/) to get started building a local server.

Follow the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4466:4466'
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            port: 5432
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres: ~
```

I builded two docker containers, one is prisma server, the other is postgres database.

As I thought after command `prisma depoly` the Model User should create a users table in the database.

But I try to check the schema in the database and got the result:

```
docker exec -it myContainer psql -U prisma
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 prisma    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
prisma=# \z // or postgres=# \z

                            Access privileges
 Schema | Name | Type | Access privileges | Column privileges | Policies
--------+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----------
(0 rows)

prisma=# \dt or postgres=# \dt
Did not find any relations.
```

Then I tried to check the volume folder in the VM machine

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
/var/lib/docker/volumes/first_prisma_postgres/_data # ls
PG_VERSION            pg_commit_ts          pg_ident.conf         pg_notify             pg_snapshots          pg_subtrans           pg_wal                postgresql.conf
base                  pg_dynshmem           pg_logical            pg_replslot           pg_stat               pg_tblspc             pg_xact               postmaster.opts
global                pg_hba.conf           pg_multixact          pg_serial             pg_stat_tmp           pg_twophase           postgresql.auto.conf  postmaster.pid
```

The data exactly exist at the VM machine, but how can I checked the data or made dump backup from it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once if you are connected to postgres in your container, you can execute normal queries.

Example:

`\l` to display all the schema

`\dt` to display all tables.

maybe connecting to database is the one you are missing.

Run - `\c schema_name` to connect to db

Once you are connected, you can execute any normal queries.

Comment: after commanding `\l`, there are four database return `postgres`, `prisma` and `template 0(1)`. I have checked every database by `\c` and `\d` and all operations return `did not find any relations`

Comment: Once you do, \l then execute \c or \connect database_name; - now you will be connected to database. Then you can perform query operations.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried `\c postgres` and `\c prisma`, then each connection I also run `\d` and `\z`. the responses are all empty

Comment: I am not sure what does \z does. \dt will return all the tables in the database you are connected to.

Comment: I have tried `\dt` and the response of each database is `Did not find any relations.` So I certainly known I can't checked the data from it

Comment: But I used the curl to call the database api, the data response as json `{data:{users:[{id: 1, content: "blablabla"}]}}`

Comment: I would first confirm if the prisma container is able to connect to the postgres container. You can try checking the logs by doing `docker logs --follow <container_name>` and see if it has any database connection errors

Comment: @prithajnath I used your way to monitor both container prisma_server and container postgres_server, I tried to insert new data into the database, but the logger did not print any new action... Is anyway to let it be alive?

Answer (score 2):

To check all volumes you can run:

```
docker volume ls
```

To check one of them:

```
docker volume inspect postgres_db
```

, where *postgres_db* is a name of your volume

As a result you may see something like this:

```
[
  {
    "CreatedAt": "2022-05-05T14:24:04Z",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.project": "s-deployment",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "2.4.1",
        "com.docker.compose.volume": "postgres_db"
    },
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/s-deployment_postgres_db/_data",
    "Name": "s-deployment_postgres_db",
    "Options": null,
    "Scope": "local"
  }
]
```